# Connecting Android Device to My Local Host Permission

Tags: android, apache, web-services, localhost, wamp

[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Following this thread .

I want to connect my Android Device to my local host using wifi (Android hotspot) .

My local pc adress is : 192.168.43.13

On my PC , it's ok i can access .

But for some reason i can't access to the local host using my android web navigator . it's says (You don't have permession to access / on this server )

Appache .

Im using wampp

Some people say that i need to change
this

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to this

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But it ain't working , please help . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution .
Under

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
```

just change

```
Require local
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: Never change the `<Directory /> section of 'httpd.conf` file. If anybody tells you to do that then you know that ___they dont know what they are doing___. So I suggest you change it back.

Comment: A safer option it to use `Require ip 192.168.43` in the `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">` then you only allow access from anyone on your internal network